# How to get the XYZ Velocity from two Lat / Lon points?

Tags: c#, mapping, gis, latitude-longitude

Lets say I have two XYZ ECEF (Earth Centered Earth Fixed) points, and I know the time it takes to get between them. How do I calculate the three dimensional xyz velocities? This is not a homework question, it's for a mapping project I'm working on and I'm not the greatest with GIS stuff.

Comment: Directly from one point to the other (through the earths crust), or, the velocity at any point as you go along the earths surface?

Comment: I don't think latitude / longitude communicate altitude / elevation information, do they? So I guess I'm mostly interested in the X and Y velocities along the earth's surface.

Comment: X,Y has little value on the surface, especially because you can never know the actual origin of the sphere. However, finding lat/lng velocities are doable.

Comment: Lat and long velocities then, how do I do that?

Comment: How you do it is going to come down to your specific requirement.  Haversine's formula is a pretty solid place to start (http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/ is an OK example of this).  But it has issues around the poles and the equator because of the Earth being a slightly squashed ellipsoid rather than a sphere.  It also does not take into elevation into account at all.  For distances under a mile, height can be compensated for with reasonable accuracy by treating the XY haversine distance and height difference as sides of a right triangle for the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: What you asking for is not tied to .NET. This question should be moved to GIS forum on StackExchange (http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you want Lat/Lng velocities. For this you need to know the time taken to travel. Then:

```
$latVelocity = ($start['lat']-$end['lat'])/$time;
$lngVelocity = ($start['lng']-$end['lng'])/$time;
```

Comment: I revised my question. I need the x y and z direction velocities from two ECEF points

Comment: @DanRedux how is this related to C#?

Comment: It's not specifically C#, but it still shows the required math fairly easily. I don't know C#, but I did know how to do the math behind it, and it's simply enough that it can be written in PHP and still make sense to any programmer.

Comment: These formulae have units of degrees/time. Degrees are not a good distance metric, so when you translate these to velocities, you could find that penguins move "faster" than cheetahs.